# About the android file management, Environment Android notion and android library plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, gluon-mobile

For creating files in Android with Java under Eclipse, I have to use:

```
File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/toto.txt");
```

So, I have to import `import android.os.Environment`.

**CASE 1:**
After a Eclipse project - Gradle - Refresh All, I get this error:

```
error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Environment;
                 ^
C:\Users\pascal\workspaceNeon\JFX_withGluon_10.8n\src\main\java\com\gluonapplication\PopUp.java:2694: error: cannot find symbol
        GluonApplication.traceSimple("Path: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable Environment
```

**CASE 2:**

Consequence: I have added "    apply plugin: 'android-library'" in my build.gradle file (see below).

In this case, on a Gradle "Refresh all", I get:

```
"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'JFX_withGluon_10.8n'.
> **android.compileSdkVersion is missing!**"
```

It seems that my **build.gradle file** is fine. I have just added: 
"apply plugin: 'android-library'".

The Java Build Path Libraries include android-25.jar.

The src/android/res/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 "<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
```

Note: Previously, in the Java source, without this file management in Android system, I had no problem for generating the .apk. I do not handle yet the gradle.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

jfxmobile {
     downConfig {
        version '3.2.0'
        plugins 'accelerometer', 'compass', 'device', 'orientation', 'storage', 'vibration', 'display', 'magnetometer', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'position'
    }

android {
        applicationPackage = 'com.gluonapplication'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/pascal/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
        resDirectory = 'src/android/res'
        compileSdkVersion = '25'
        buildToolsVersion = '25.0.1'


    }

 ios {
         infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU USING **ECLIPSE** IN 2017 ? ECLIPSE IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED!

Comment: If you remove the `gluon` tag, people will take it as a regular Android question. Use `gluon` and `javafxports` tags to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including several 'plugins' in your build file under the `downConfig` block. These plugins are Charm Down [libraries](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/tip/plugins/?at=default) that provide an agnostic API, meaning that you add them in your main Java package, and there is a hidden platform-specific implementation that will be used once you deploy your application to any of the possible platforms (desktop, android or iOS).

In case you want to access a given folder, you have the `Storage` plugin.

Check the API [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/latest/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html).

You can get a private folder (bundled within your app), or a public folder.

For data related to your app, I'll use a private folder:

```
File localRoot = Services.get(StorageService.class)
            .flatMap(s -> s.getPrivateStorage())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error retrieving private storage"));
```

so now you can create your file there:

```
File docsFolder = new File(localRoot + "/toto.txt");
```

For a public one, first you need to check if it is available (media is mounted and you have write permissions):

```
boolean storageAvailable = Services.get(StorageService.class)
        .map(service -> service.isExternalStorageWritable())
        .orElse(false);
```

Then you have to select which folder you want to get, i.e. `Documents`:

```
File publicRoot = Services.get(StorageService.class)
        .flatMap(s -> s.getPublicStorage("Documents"))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error retrieving public storage"));
```

and now you can create your file there:

```
File docsFolder = new File(publicRoot + "/toto.txt");
```

Finally, if you check how the project is structured, you have a main package that is common to every platform: you can only place Java code there. Then you have an Android package, so if you need it you can add android API, but only in this package.

The Charm Down plugins are precisely an example of how you can create a service with common API on main package (i.e. see `StorageService` [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/1942aa27c6b60d890511667cf64c3f9d8a0e69b6/plugins/plugin-storage/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)), and its different implementations (i.e. see `AndroidStorageService` [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/1942aa27c6b60d890511667cf64c3f9d8a0e69b6/plugins/plugin-storage/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidStorageService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand better how avoiding to write dedicated codes to a platform. Now, I am trying to use your 1st solution.

Comment: I have implemented  your 1st solution and tested it with Android. That works fine: **files can be written, read or deleted in a private Android directory**.

Comment: Ok. When one of the provided answers works for you, you should mark it as accepted (green tick), as others will find it later and will know is useful. You can upvote as well if you like any of those answers. This is how SO works...

Comment: how to make a "green tick" in a SO discussion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To move away from all of these complications, I think you should try with Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry, but I use also javafxports (gluon charm down) in this application that is already developed for desktop too, without Android studio.(Note: This application is common to these two platforms)